# Delete gridview columns and keep state was postback using JQuery

Tags: jquery, asp.net, gridview

I am building an application using ASP.NET. In that application there is a database driven GridView. I'm using the below JQuery code to hide the column when clicking on the GridView header. However. It has worked great until I start doing postback/refresh page, where the UI/Gridview obviously resets itself to its initial state.

So my question is, what are the best practices for saving the gridview state and restoring jquery/UI state between postbacks?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
       $("#<%=GridView1.ClientID%> th").filter("th:not(:first-child)").click(function() {
           var iIndex = $(this).closest("th").prevAll("th").length;
           $(this).parents("#<%=GridView1.ClientID%>").find("tr").each(function() {
              $(this).find("td:eq(" + iIndex + ")").remove();
              $(this).find("th:eq(" + iIndex + ")").remove();

           });
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

With ASP.NET web forms it's tricky to maintain UI consistency between postbacks when updating the DOM via JavaScript.

Usually the best you can do is to use an UpdatePanel and do all your changes on the server.

An alternative would be to have a hidden field where you keep track of changes that you make on the client, that way you can replicate them on the server to remain consistent.

Comment: Hi diegog, n relation to the second instance hidden field where you keep track of changes' is there any chance you can give me a basic example of what you mean?